# Lazy loading dynamic images image

Tags: json, image, react-native, lazy-loading

I am picking images from JSON and want to load that in lazyimageload

```
renderRow = (file) => {
  var imageURL = require(file.image_url);
    return <View
        style={styles.view}>
        <LazyloadView
            host="listExample"
            style={styles.file}>
             <LazyloadImage
                    host="listExample"
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={imageURL}
                    animation={false}/>
            <View style={styles.detail}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{file.first_name} {file.last_name}</Text>
                <Text><Text style={styles.title}>email: </Text><Text style={styles.email}>{file.email}</Text></Text>
                <Text style={styles.ip}><Text style={styles.title}>last visit ip: </Text>{file.ip_address}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.gender}>
                <Text style={[styles.genderText, file.gender === 'Male' ? styles.male : styles.female]}>{file.gender}</Text>
            </View>
        </LazyloadView>
    </View>;
};
```

But getting exception "Requiring unknown modules "./images/image.png'. if you are sure the module is there try restarting the packager or running npm install. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically pull in local images with require. The reason is when the packager encounters a `require` it tries to bundle that file with your app. It can't bundle the image if the path is dynamic. To load a dynamic image you would either need to pull it from the network or if you have a specific set of images that could end up being used you could `require` each and then use the output of that `require` depending on information passed in.

```
const image1 = require('./image1.png');
const image2 = require('./image2.png');
{...}
render() {
    return (
        <Image source={aRandomBool ? image1 : image2} />
    );
}
```

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources

Comment: But I have to load images from JSON file and there is one Image URL associated with every row item. The images and even data are dynamic